# Openpyxl - number formatted as text - percentages

Tags: python, number-formatting, percentage, openpyxl

I am scraping some data from a website and putting it into excel.  However, I am getting the message from excel that the numbers are formatted as text with that annoying green arrow thing.  I have found code that converts numbers - however, some of the data is percentages and it doesn't fix that.  Is there a way to also convert the percentages.

Here is the code that I found that converts the numbers.

```
f = open(csv_filename,'rb')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):
    for column_index, cell in enumerate(row):
        column_letter = get_column_letter((column_index + 1))
        s = cell
        try:
            s=float(s)
        except ValueError:
            pass

        ws.cell('%s%s'%(column_letter, (row_index + 1))).value = s
```

Any help on converting percentages so they don't store as text? There are numerous columns, some are percents and some are plain numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: openpyxl does have an `guess_types` option for workbooks but it's much better to write your own type conversion code.

Comment: Can you help me in how I would go about doing that?  Would I write code to explicitly tell it which columns to make percents? I am still relatively new to python so any help you can give me is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, you can try using `wb = Workbook(guess_types=True)` and see if openpyxl gets it right. Otherwise, yes, you do it column by column. You'll need to add information about which columns need special handling. NB. you don't need to work out the coordinates manually as `ws.cell()` accepts numbers for row and column. Try it out.

Comment: I tried adding that at the end of the code and I got a NameError - Workbook is not defined.  Also, I have another variable called wb. Do I just need to change the wb in your code to another name?

Comment: I figured the NameError out but now get the following: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'guess_types'      Also, I have another variable named wb - do I need to change the wb in your code to another variable?

Comment: I figured it out after extensive searching : You can also use it as an input argument in the load_workbook method.                                                     
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("any.xlsx", guess_types=True) – eeScott Oct 20 '16 at 18:16

Comment: Sure, but your code doesn't indicate whether you're opening an existing workbook or creating a new one.